# Entity framework - Lazy loading based on a unique nonclustered key in a table

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, lazy-loading

Entity framework does not seem to lazy load related records if the key is unique and non-clustered. Just wanted to know if I am doing something wrong.

Say I have two tables - Employee and EmployeeTransactions.

EmployeeID is UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED but not the primary key of the table.

Assume for the question's sake, it is generated by another data base and inserted into the employee table.

However, most other tables have an EmployeeID which is a foreign key to table Employees

```
  --Table Employee 
  DBGEneratedPK
  EmployeeID (Unique NonClustered, Indexed)

  -- Table EmployeeTransactions 
  TransactionID (PK Clustered)
  EMployeeID (FK into Table A)
  Other columns
```

Now, when I use entity framework to retreive an employee it does not show me the option of lazy loading
employeetransactions?

```
  employee.employeetransactions
```

Is this a limitation of EF?

Comment: Depends on your mappings. Please show the details.

Comment: I am just using the generated edmx. Should I do some explicit maping in the edmx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is limitation of EF. EF supports relations only when the key in principal table is a primary key. Just [unique keys are currently not supported](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1050579-unique-constraint-i-e-candidate-key-support).